# How can I prevent a line from appearing on top of the legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I'm plotting a 2 axes graph with matplotlib. The problem I struggle with is that when I plot the second line (pH), it appears on top of the previous legend. Is there any way to send the line to the background (as we do in Office Word).

I would also like to know if there's any way to merge the two different legends (one for each axis) in a single legend.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.set_xlabel('Tiempo (horas)')
ax1.set_ylabel('Concentración (mg/L)')
ax1.plot(t,NH4,'m-',label='NH4')
ax1.plot(t,NO2,'b--',label='NO2')
ax1.plot(t,NO3,'g-',label='NO3')
ax1.plot(t,OD,'c+',label='OD')

plt.grid(axis='both')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax2.set_ylabel('pH',color='red')
ax2.plot(t,pH,'r',label='pH')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='red')
ax2.legend(loc='center right')
ax1.legend(loc='upper center', mode='expand', ncol=len(ax1.lines))
plt.show()
```

I would like either to send the red line to the background, or merge the two labels into a single one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `zorder` attribute (https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html) on every patch (`plot`, `legend`) to manually control the vertical placement of objects on the figure.

If you don't specify this `matplotlib` will try to figure it out automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@Droid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4105440/droid) answer, note that you can directly set the `zorder` of the legend to a high value (to be drawn over the plots) with `plt.legend().set_zorder(X)` (or `.set(zorder=X)`). The default legend `zorder` is `5`.

Answer (score 0):

The lines and legend all have the same zorder. So, they are rendered in the order which the code is written. The way to get the right effect is to set the zorder for the `ax1` higher (say 1). But this will push the `pH` line behind and makes is invisible. So, next turn frame off for `ax2`, so that you can see the line. Then turn on the frame for `ax2`. This will give you the required effect and keep the pH line behind the legend.

Now, to merge the two legends, get the legend handles and the labels using `get_legend_handles_labels()`, then add the handles and labels and create a combined legend.

The updated code is given below. Hope this helps...

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_xlabel('Tiempo (horas)')
ax1.set_ylabel('Concentración (mg/L)')
ax1.plot(t,NH4,'m-',label='NH4')
ax1.plot(t,NO2,'b--',label='NO2')
ax1.plot(t,NO3,'g-',label='NO3')
ax1.plot(t,OD,'c+',label='OD')
plt.grid(axis='both')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.set_ylabel('pH',color='red')
ax2.plot(t,pH,'r',label='pH')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='red')

# Get the handles and labels for ax1 and ax2
h1, l1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
h2, l2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()

# Create legend by adding the columns
legend=ax1.legend(h1+h2, l1+l2,loc='upper center', mode='expand', ncol=len(ax1.lines)+1)

ax1.set_zorder(1) # make it on top
ax1.set_frame_on(False) # make it transparent
ax2.set_frame_on(True) # make sure there is any background

plt.show()
```

**Output plot**

[image]